# Unexpected result when removing an element from a slice

Tags: go, slice

I encountered unexpected results when I remove the first element from slice, this is my test code, hope to help you understand my confuse
define structure

```
type A struct {
    member int
}

func (a A) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", a.member)
}

type B struct {
    a      A
    aPoint *A
}

func (b B) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("a: %v, aPoint: %v", b.a, b.aPoint)
}
```

below is my test case

```
func TestSliceRemoveFirstEle(t *testing.T) {
    demo := []B{
        {a: A{member: 1}},
        {a: A{member: 2}},
        {a: A{member: 3}},
    }

    for i := range demo {
        demo[i].aPoint = &demo[i].a
    }

    fmt.Println("demo before operation is ", demo) // result: demo before operation is  [a: 1, aPoint: 1 a: 2, aPoint:2 a: 3, aPoint: 3]
    demo = append(demo[:0], demo[1:]...)
    fmt.Println("demo after operation is ", demo) // result: demo after operation is  [a: 2, aPoint: 3 a: 3, aPoint: 3]
}
```

my expected result is `[a: 2, aPoint: 2 a: 3, aPoint: 3]`

when I use another way adding element to the slice, it work well.

```
func TestAddSliceRemoveFirstEle(t *testing.T) {
    demo := make([]B, 0, 3)
    a1 := A{member: 1}
    a2 := A{member: 2}
    a3 := A{member: 3}
    demo = append(demo, B{a: a1, aPoint: &a1}, B{a: a2, aPoint: &a2}, B{a: a3, aPoint: &a3})

    fmt.Println("demo before operation is ", demo) // result: demo before operation is  [a: 1, aPoint: 1 a: 2, aPoint: 2 a: 3, aPoint: 3]
    demo = append(demo[:0], demo[1:]...)
    fmt.Println("demo after operation is ", demo) // result: demo after operation is  [a: 2, aPoint: 2 a: 3, aPoint: 3]
}
```

I'm confused about the result, what happened in the first case after removing element from slice, and what's the difference between these two implementations?

Comment: You say your expected result is `[a: 1, aPoint: 1 a: 2, aPoint: 2 a: 3, aPoint: 3]`, that looks like a typo since in the "working well" version the result is `[a: 2, aPoint: 2 a: 3, aPoint: 3]`.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake, my expected result is `[a: 2, aPoint: 2 a: 3, aPoint: 3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example all the A structs exist only in the slice and the pointer points to elements of the slice.
In your second example, the A structs exist outside the slice and so there are no pointers against the elements of the slice.

As per the golang append specification at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices

> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values, append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise, append re-uses the underlying array.

Since we are decreasing the size the underlying array is big enough so we are reusing it.
This is what the underlying array of capacity 3 looks like before and after the reslicing

```
123 - before
233 - after
```

What pointed at '2' before is now pointing at '3' as your example shows, a simpler way to see can be through this playground

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    mySlice := []int{1, 2, 3}
    one := &mySlice[0]
    two := &mySlice[1]
    three := &mySlice[2]
    fmt.Printf("%v-%d\n%v-%d\n%v-%d\n",one,*one,two,*two,three,*three)
    fmt.Printf("%v cap %d\n",mySlice, cap(mySlice))
    mySlice = append(mySlice[:1],mySlice[2:]...)
    fmt.Printf("%v cap %d\n",mySlice, cap(mySlice))
    fmt.Printf("%v-%d\n%v-%d\n%v-%d\n",one,*one,two,*two,three,*three)
}
```

Where you'll see

```
0xc0000be000-1
0xc0000be008-2
0xc0000be010-3
[1 2 3] cap 3
[1 3] cap 3
0xc0000be000-1
0xc0000be008-3
0xc0000be010-3
```

In short, taking pointers out of elements of a slice and reslicing it will always cause these kind of errors.
It could also cause memory leak issues as per the footnote here https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#delete-without-preserving-order

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the `aPoint` pointers still point to the same address, but the values at those addresses changed.

After the append it is `demo[0].aPoint == &demo[1].a` and *not* `demo[0].aPoint == &demo[0].a`.

https://play.golang.org/p/HoNhFlxTEFN

---

The [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) `demo[:0]` will result in a new slice of length `0` that points to the same underlying array as the `demo` slice. The elements stored in that array are still there, they are not discarded.

So after `demo[:0]` the underlying array is still:

```golang
[
    B{a:1,<pointer_to_idx:0_field_a>},
    B{a:2,<pointer_to_idx:1_field_a>},
    B{a:3,<pointer_to_idx:2_field_a>},
]
```

`demo[1:]...` drops the first element and passes the remaining two elements to `append`. Then `append` takes those two elements and updates the underlying array's first two elements. After that the underlying array will look like this:

```golang
[
    B{a:2,<pointer_to_idx:1_field_a>},
    B{a:3,<pointer_to_idx:2_field_a>},
    B{a:3,<pointer_to_idx:2_field_a>},
]
```

Notice that now, the `aPointer` field of the 0th element of the array points to the 1st element's `a` field. And the `aPointer` field of the 1st element points to the 2nd element's `a` field.